# Would an experimentally shown electron substructure prove stringtheory wrong?

Tags: electrons, string-theory, beyond-the-standard-model

Suppose it is shown in an experiment that the electron has a substructure, i.e. it would be made up from some kind of preons. Would this prove stringtheory wrong? I mean, in string theory, the electron is visualized as a single string in the "electron vibration state", which contradicts any substructure. Or would the theory just have to be adjusted?

Comment: The cynical answer is that the theory would be adjusted to accommodate any uncomfortable experimental facts, e.g. perhaps the substructure could be interpreted in a stringy way. The philosophy of science answer is that theories are rarely completely discarded because of one incompatible fact, even though in retrospect it is convenient to describe it that way.

Comment: @MartinC. I don't think so. Any serious _single_ experimental can invalidate complete theory. You are wrong. Check completely [abandoned theories in Physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superseded_theories_in_science#Physics). Also check this [nice book about Discarded Theories](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/resisting-scientific-realism/discarded-theories/A1ECAFBD68554DD634C05A4A5FBB9DDF). The problem is that usually people discuss only successful theories, but they rarely know/talk about failed ones.

Answer (score 6):

"String theory", without further specifics, is like "quantum field theory" a theoretical *framework*, not a single theory with a single set of predictions. You can't prove "quantum field theory" wrong by showing some particle that is elementary in the [Standard Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) - which is one specific instance of a quantum field theory - isn't actually elementary, you're just proving the Standard Model wrong.

The specific particle content of a specific instance of string theory depends, for example, greatly on the chosen [compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactification_(physics)) of the extra dimensions. Showing that a particular particle content is not realized in our world just shows that the particular compactifications associated with that particle content do not model our reality. It says nothing - in the positive or negative - about the validity of string theory as a framework unless you can show that the specific particle content observed would be impossible to obtain from *any* string theory.